# How to keep data when navigate to another fragment use navigation direction?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I have 2 fragment: `fragment1` and `fragment2`

I'm using `Navigation` to navigate `fragment1` to `fragment2`:

```
val action = Fragment1Directions.actionFragment1ToFragment2()
navController.navigate(action)
```

My `fragment1` contain `RecyclerView` with data change. When I clicked to item in `fragment1`'s `RecyclerView` will open `fragment2`. And when I press back button I back to `fragment1` with loss data.

I want to keep my data when move to `fragment2` and back to `fragment1` (`fragment2` like popup in web). How can I do it.

Update:

I used `View Model` to keep `LiveData`. but when I back from `fragment2` to `fragment1`, `fragment1` reloaded. How can I open `fragment2` and hold `fragment1` (temp open `fragment2`). I'm using `Navigation`

Comment: So how are you [saving your fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state)?

Comment: You need to have A Shared ViewModel between the two fragments to make sure that there is no data loss.  Since ViewModel persist and the data stays

Comment: When I press back to fragment1, fragment1 reloaded. How can I open fragment2 and hold fragment1. I used Navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. use `View Model` to keep `LiveData`
2. use `Dialog destinations` for fragment2. Visit https://gist.github.com/utkukutlu/bd2e37253e7184179d923321e3ea72c1 for more detail with `Dialog destinations`

Learned experience:

1. Navigation fragment only replace not have add. I want Navigation act like add so I use `Dialog destinations`
2. I use `Dialog destinations` so I have to use `View Model` to keep `LiveData` when I update my data in `fragment1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using livedata to keep track of your data.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.